# Choosing the right Amazon Web Service (AWS) for a Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

As I understand it, there are a number of AWS options available for a Ruby On Rails deployment.

- [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) (with or without [rubber](https://github.com/rubber/rubber) gem)
- [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)
- [OpsWorks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/)

(are there any others?)

Although the various services features are well documented in their respective FAQs, what I find is lacking is a comparison between these services.

What questions should I be answering to determine the most appropriate service for my needs?

Comment: Under the covers it will all be EC2. Elastic Beanstalk and OpsWorks are just automation tools on top of EC2.

Comment: I think you should provide more info on your app needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions you should answer to know which is the most appropriate service for your needs are:

**1. What level of customisation do my app needs?**

Depending on your app’s components your needs may differ. You may need to use a different Load Balancer than HAproxy (default LB in EB and apparently OpsWork) or you may want to use an Ubuntu OS (for instance EB uses RedHat) cos you are building a bitcoin app and the bitcoin daemon is easily available in aptitude. etc

EC2 = IaaS = higher degree of freedom. 
EB = PaaS = much more difficult to modify the underlying layers (but still possible). 
I haven’t really used OpsWork but regarding easiness of modification it seems it falls in-between the former two. (A tool like Scalr)

**2. Do I really have the time and resources to take care of the infrastructure or do I need to focus on coding my app's logic?**

Can you devote your precious time thinking about, and maintaining a modular infrastructure so you can increase efficiency in your deployments?

If your answer is yes, then go with vanilla EC2/AWS and rubber or a similar solution for scripting the system and deployments. *Infrastructure as code rocks.*

If the answer is no, you’re better off with any PaaS solution. It can be Elastic Beanstalk, or Heroku, Engine Yard, or docker/dokku (cheap and really nice). Then you can re-engineer the system as-you-go.

**3. How easy will be to scale/grow (regarding costs and engineering) with the service I’ve picked?**

This question is tricky. Imagine your app gets serious traction. Once you have chosen a possible deployment strategy, you must have a general idea about how easy would be to scale, or add components to the system, and its effect on the pricing… without falling in a big “over-engineering” mistake (imagining future problems that do not yet exist)

Re-engineering all your app will cost you time and money, so the correct initial choice should strike a balance between “easy/cheap to modify” and leave your options “open" for adding additional components in the coming future, w/o worrying too much about it. Your time is precious.

**Another options**

As for any other “services”, there aren’t more service options at AWS I can remember now, but you have a ton of different ways to achieve deployments to AWS in a seamless manner… i.e:

- Vagrant + Chef
- Vagrant + Rubber
- Boto/AWSCLI + Capistrano
- Boto + Cloud-Formation + Capistrano
- Rubber + Vanilla Orchrestration Services: Puppet, Chef, SaltStack
- Hosted Cloud Orchrestration: RightScale, Scalr, etc
- CI Servers controlling all of the above (my fav)
- Docker/dokku (your own PaaS, ***easy and cheap*** heroku compatible deployments)

0,02

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for the detailed answer SDude

Answer (score 2):

I personally would use the standard EC2.  I feel more at home with a straight up install.  One thing that I have looked into using but as of yet have not is [Cloud 66](https://www.cloud66.com/features) deployment service.  Think of it as rubber on steroids.

Answer (score 1):

This is very context dependent, but i'd recommend you try Elastic Beanstalk first. If you are familiar to Chef, OpsWorks may be more interesting or if you have very specific architecture, CloudFormation and direct EC2 may be more interesting.

DISCLAIMER: This may be a bit biased as i'm using (and liking) Elastic Beanstalk very much.

Comment: And @datasage is right, those are all on top of EC2.